# How to mock write csv/xlsx function pytest/unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

New to Unit testing and getting difficulties while mocking write file function.

```
def write_files(a, b):
    if os.path.dirname(arg1):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(arg1), exist_ok=True)
    if "xlsx" in format1:
        get_write_xlsx(a, b)
    if "txt" in format1:
        get_write_txt(a, b)
    elif format_x:
        print( please ignored.")
    if "json" in format1:
        get_write_json(a, b)
```

In the above function `get_write_xlsx(a, b)`, `get_write_txt(a, b)` and `get_write_json(a, b)` these are another function call and want mock this `write_files(a, b)` as well as the other function also.
Appreciate for your help.

Thanks

Comment: To write efficient unit test, you must first write docstring to describe your function. Tell us what are a and b. Also, that's not how you check if a file is xlsx or txt. Use format1.endswith('xlsx") instead.

Comment: @JamieNguyen, `a` and `b` is `string` you can consider and also `format1` is `string`. and the function is existing in the module, so need to test it by mocking it

Comment: Hi @JamieNguyen, Whatever changes you suggest in the code that's fine but this is existing code and need to test that code. And asking help for the same.

Comment: where is `format1` being defined? same for `format_x`. they are not being passed in to the function